# Robocopy Skipping All files Targeted

Tags: windows, powershell, script, robocopy

Good Afternoon,

I'm attempting to use robocopy with Powershell to recursively grab all files from sub-directories and moving them to one "root" directory. I tried doing this with copy-item but it would hang, which is a huge pain when trying to copy over 10k files.

```
function fcopy ($SourceDir,$DestinationDir)
{
    Get-ChildItem $SourceDir -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object ($_) {
        $SourceFile = $_.Name
        $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_
        if (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
            $i = 0
            while (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
                $i += 1
                $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_.basename + $i + $_.extension
            }
        } else {
            #
            Robocopy.exe $($SourceDir) $($DestinationDir) $($SourceFile) /L /V  /COPY:DAT

            #Write-Output $SourceFile
        }
            #
            Robocopy.exe $($SourceDir) $($DestinationDir) $($SourceFile) /L /V /COPY:DAT 
            #Write-Output $SourceFile
    }
}

fcopy -SourceDir 'A:\User Name Inbox Search_Export\08.04.2022-0829AM\User' -DestinationDir 'A:\Destination'
```

However, if I run this, here's what I get for output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Friday, August 5, 2022 3:09:51 PM
   Source : A:\User Name Inbox Search_Export\08.04.2022-0829AM\User\
     Dest : A:\Destination\

    Files : IAH JUNE.pdf

  Options : /V /L /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           0    A:\User Name Inbox Search_Export\08.04.2022-0829AM\User
```

Robocopy appears to list the file, but then I just receive a code of 0 and the source directory. The destination directory is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the correct filename `IAH JUNE.pdf` or `JUNE.pdf` ?

Comment: [1] `ForEach-Object ($_) {` is bad syntax; remove `($_)` [2] `$DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_` will give you a bad file path. Have you checked that at all? Tip: use Join-Path [3] Using subexpressions like `$($SourceDir)` is redundant

Comment: Even after making changes, robocopy does not seem to do anything. It's odd because if I write-output, I receive the proper output: 
`A:\Test Source`
`A:\Test Destination`
`Test File.doc`

Comment: I figured it out. I was definitely pointing Robocopy to the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

It is the /L switch
Specifies that files are to be listed only (and not copied, deleted, or time stamped).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).